# Getting different results in training a tensorflow model using keras classes and strings for compilation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Hi I am trying to train a tensorflow convolutional model on a small portion of the kaggle dogs-vs-cats dataset.

I am building the model in the following way:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import image_dataset_from_directory
import pathlib

new_base_dir = pathlib.Path("../8/cats_vs_dogs_small")
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
        layers.RandomZoom(0.2),
    ]
)

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(180, 180, 3))
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = layers.Rescaling(1./255)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    new_base_dir/"train",
    image_size=(180,180),
    batch_size=32
)

validation_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    new_base_dir/"validation",
    image_size=(180,180),
    batch_size=32
)

test_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    new_base_dir/"test",
    image_size=(180,180),
    batch_size=32
)
```

and I tried to compile in two ways, that I expected to the same:

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
             metrics=[keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
```

and

```
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="rmsprop",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

and then training with

```
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    epochs=5)
```

However, I am getting different results in the two compilations. In the first case the model does not seem to train at all (see first figure).
Whereas in the second case, the model is learning (see second figure).

Is there any difference between the two compilations? Why?

[image: Using keras classes when compiling]

[image: Using using stringsa]

**Getting the dataset**
To get the dataset and use a smaller version if you have a kaggle account you can do

```
!kaggle competitions download -c dogs-vs-cats
!unzip -qq train.zip
```

(if from a terminal and not from a Jupyter notebook remove the `!`) and to get a smaller version of the dataset, you can use the following script

```
import os, shutil, pathlib

original_dir = pathlib.Path("./train")
new_base_dir = pathlib.Path("cats_vs_dogs_small")

def make_subset(subset_name, start_index, end_index):
    for category in ("cat", "dog"):
        dir = new_base_dir / subset_name / category
        os.makedirs(dir)
        fnames = [f"{category}.{i}.jpg" for i in range(start_index, end_index)]
        for fname in fnames:
            shutil.copyfile(src=original_dir / fname,
                            dst=dir / fname)

make_subset("train", start_index=0, end_index=1000)
make_subset("validation", start_index=1000, end_index=1500)
make_subset("test", start_index=1500, end_index=2500)
```

The example is taken from [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/chapter08_intro-to-dl-for-computer-vision.ipynb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the string "accuracy" is converted to `tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()` (which turns a float into 0-1 automatically with 0.5 as the threshold) under the hood. In your first case, you are using `tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()` which requires exact match while your model only outputs a float number probability instead of 0-1.

See the official documentation:

> When you pass the strings 'accuracy' or 'acc', we convert this to one of tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy, tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy, tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy based on the loss function used and the model output shape.